# Debug Docker that quits immediately?

Tags: python, docker

I am following the official docker tutorial:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#build-the-app

I can successfully build the Docker image (after creating the Dockerfile, app.py and requirements.txt) and see it:

```
docker build -t friendlyhello .
docker ps -a
```

However, it quits immediately when running

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

I cannot find the way to find why it did not work

1) "docker ps -a" - says the container exited
2) docker logs "container name" returns no information about logs
3) I can attach the shell to it:

```
docker run  -p 4000:80 friendlyhello /bin/sh
```

but I did not manage to find (grep) any logging information there (in /var/log)
4) attaching foreground and detached mode with -t and -d did not help

What else could I do?

Comment: `docker ps -a` shows you the exit code. What is it?

Comment: it shows Exited(0)

Comment: 0 means exit ok. What is the command or entry point? You can see it with `docker inspect`

Comment: Post your app.py and dockerfile

Comment: docker inspect does work, but there is no interesting information - what exactly is "entry point" there ?

Comment: app.py and Dockerfile are identical to the ones on the Docker website link I mentioned.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: I just built that Docker image now and seems to work just fine. Are you sure you have the requirements.text and app.py in the directory where your Dockerfile is? As they will get added when you run docker build -t friendlyhello .

Comment: requirements.txt is fine, only 2 lines, there are no complains when it gets build. Could the issue be related to that I am on MacOS?

Comment: I am using Mac OS too :) so that wouldn't be a problem, I would suggest you remove all the exited containers and the image and create a directory where you will put the Dockerfile as well as the other 2 files and try to re-build it using docker build --no-cache -t friendlyhello .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: a docker exec on an exited (stopped) container should not be possible (see [moby issue 30361](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30361))

> `docker logs` and `docker inspect` on a stopped container should still be possible, but docker exec indeed not.

You should see

```
Error response from daemon: Container a21... is not running
```

So a docker inspect of the image you are running should reveal the entrypoint and cmd, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753416/6309).
The normal behavior is the one described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41792200/6309).

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue...and it drove me nuts. I am using Docker Toolbox as I am running Windows 7. I ran `docker events&` prior to my `docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello`. It showed me nothing more than the container starts, and exits pretty much straight away. `docker logs <container id>` showed nothing.

I was just about to give up when I came across a [troubleshooting page](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/faqs/troubleshoot/) with the suggestion to remove the docker machine and re-create it. I know that might sound like a sledgehammer type solution, but the examples seemed to show that the re-create downloads the latest release. I followed the steps shown and it worked! If it helps anyone the steps I ran were;

`docker-machine stop default`

`docker-machine rm default`

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Re-creating the example files, building the image and then running it now gives me;

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

And with Docker Toolbox running, I can access this at `http://192.168.99.100:4000/` and now I get;

```
Hello World!
Hostname: ca4507de3f48
Visits: cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled
```